# Failed to getClass for org.jacoco.maven.AgentMojo - Jenkins fails to build with JaCoCo maven plugin but works locally

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jacoco

I've added `JaCoCo` plugin to my `Maven` plugins, and can generate coverage report successfully locally.

However after I've commited the changed `pom.xml` and `Jenkins` tries to build the `Maven` project (consisting of multiple modules) the build fails with the output like this:

```
[HUDSON] Collecting dependencies info
[HUDSON] Collecting dependencies info
[HUDSON] Collecting dependencies info
[HUDSON] Collecting dependencies info
[JENKINS] Recording test results
[WARNING] Failed to getClass for org.jacoco.maven.AgentMojo
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/xy xyz1
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/xy xyz2
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/xy xyz3
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/xy xyz4
channel stopped
Finished: FAILURE
```

The only warning I get is the `Failed to getClass for org.jacoco.maven.AgentMojo` so I assume this could cause the build failure.

First I've thought that it's because a proxy setting, but I've added the same `settings.xml` to the `Jenkins` build as I use locally (with which the plugin is used successfully).

Also I've tried to look up this specific error in several places with no luck.

Also tried to change the pom executions, but since it's working locally I think there's no reason in changing the following Maven pom.xml setting:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>post-unit-test</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Why Jenkins does not log any more errors than that simple `[WARNING]` line?

What can be the reason `Jenkins` fails to `getClass` while locally the `Maven` build runs successfully?

Can I get `JaCoCo` coverage without adding the maven plugin to the xml? (From what I've found it is needed to be added for getting to work the `Jenkins` plugin)

Comment: Have you tried to run Maven with DEBUG option? Simple add `-X` to the job's command line: Example: `-X clean install`. You will get more tracing into the output console.

Comment: I've already set  `-X -e` yet no more output is coming. Something else must  have been set wrongly, but can't find out what exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Jenkins JaCoCo plugin to do that. You just need to specify where your java src files, .class files and test classes are. The plugin also enables the html report output to be accessible from Jenkins interface.

Comment: Don't you need a jacoco.exec for that?

Comment: Oh sorry I didnt see that you want to avoid the xml part. I've compared your code with mine and saw that the only difference is you didnt provide prepare-agent goal in your JaCoCo configuration.

Comment: I did provide the `prepare-agent` goal, and that's where the jenkins build fails most probably.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the destFile for prepare-agent goal and dataFile for report goal?

Comment: Yes, first I've tried with those. But Jenkins doesn't find the AgentMojo, so can't really prepare the agent as far as I see.

Comment: The first thing comes to my mind is to install Jenkins JaCoCo plugin (event if you dont use it), just to make sure all JaCoCo libraries and their third party dependencies are installed.

Comment: It's installed in Jenkins (that was my first step), so it doesn't solve my problem unfortunately. What bothers me is the lack of real error logs and the cause of why the jacoco plugin causes the build to fail.

Answer (score 0):

The suspicious bit for me is that you have attached the `report` goal to the `test` phase, which seems to be wrong: The report about the test coverage can't be done before the tests are performed, so you must chose another of the next phases. For example, the `verify` phase (which is the default phase for the `report` goal).

Comment: I've changed it to default, yet the same output is coming unfortunately